# Magento - How to Manually Change Base URL / Domain?

Tags: magento

I've done searches for this, but can only find answers on how to do this through the admin panel (which I can't reach).

I have a live Magento installation that I'm going to be doing some new development on.

So I'm setting up a development site on a subdomain of the main site's url (http://test.mydomain.com)

The problem I'm having is that somewhere in the `Mage::run()` bootstrapper, the site's getting redirected to the www subdomain.

I've changed the following 2 records in the DB:

```
mysql> select * from core_config_data where value like '%mydomain.com%';
| config_id | scope   | scope_id | path                   | value                         |
+-----------+---------+----------+------------------------+-------------------------------+
|         2 | default |        0 | web/unsecure/base_url  | http://test.mydomain.com/     |
|         3 | default |        0 | web/secure/base_url    | http://test.mydomain.com/     |
```

- I've also ensured that the 'local.xml' config is pointing to the new dev DB.
- I've also deleted the entire /var/cache
- I've also removed all htaccess subdomain redirects
- I've also restarted Apache.

No luck, still redirecting.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So it turns out the problem was that Apache didn't have write permissions to the `WEBROOT/var` directory, so Magento was using its cache from the system `/tmp` directory. (thanks for the tip, **Fiasco Labs**!)

In case someone gets here from Google, I'll reiterate the steps...

**How to Manually Change Domain in Magento**

1. Update your `core_config_data` table to edit the two records for `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url`
2. Delete the contents of `WEBROOT/var/cache`
3. Update / edit any `.htaccess` domain redirects you may have added
4. Restart Apache
5. Make sure Apache has write permissions to `WEBROOT/var`
6. If you created a new DB, ensure that the `WEBROOT/app/etc/local.xml`  is pointing to it.
7. If you're using Chrome, clear your browser cache! (Chrome caches 301s)

That's about it.  Cheers.

Comment: Basically what I do bi-weekly to sync my dev server with the live server. As an added thought, if you are using a CDN for image serving, or modules that require separate keys for dev domains, you can automate the MySQL updates for those as well as the base_url entries through a .sql file. Also, when moving to a new server, make sure the permissions are set properly on the var/ folder. Magento will write its cache to the system /tmp folder if it's not able to use var/ and this causes grief since Magento will use the cached information in /tmp and redirect to the old site.

Comment: Aha, that must be what it was then!  When I created the new site the first time, I didn't properly set the permissions on the ./var directory.  It must have been grabbing from /tmp (which had been in use in the past).  The second time around, I did a `chown -R www-data:my_username ./*` on the whole site due to laziness (since it's a dev site), which is probably why it worked!  Thanks for that added tip!!

Comment: It's a rock that hangs up many a site move. And is one of those things that mysteriously self-heals when a server reboot is done and the /tmp directory gets cleared, only to have something get saved in the cache and yet again cause mysterious problems where things won't change even when the var/cache folder gets emptied manually. Every time you hear, **"I made (template/layout/config) changes, cleared the cache and nothing happened!"**, immediately think **"gotta check directory permissions so the web server can write to the var/ folder and subfolders"**.

Comment: **Important: Most guides on the Internet have all the above steps except 'Restart Apache'. Something I didn't think of.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `FLUSHALL` command on `redis-cli`, maybe you have a cached database.

It worked for me.